# Pandas : Calculate moving average within group

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to calculate moving average by 'category'
but I can't. I calculated like in the picture but I think there is sth wrong.
How can I fix it?

Comment: check out this tutorial https://www.statology.org/pandas-moving-average-by-group/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
df['average_value'] = df.groupby('category')['rawValue'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).mean())
```